# Biconnected component

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I have read this wonderful algorithm for finding the articulation points in a connected graph https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component

In the algorithm lowpoint is calculated for every node which means the lowest depth of neighbors of all descendants of given node .

How does this low point helps to find the articulation point and why it should be calculated ? Especially the non root nodes . I want the significance of lowpoint in the algorithm .

Comment: Components seem to be contiguous sections of a graph that have their own conceptualized grouping observable by whether they group further, which implies lack of external connection beyond a boundary of some rational coherence. By searching for the "lowest number of connections" between these (observed) components, it would seem you find the leverage for articulation of a component itself against another component, which would be where the graph articulates into systems of interconnectedness. Hence, removing that node will generate a new understanding, e.g. disrupt the graph's coherence.

Answer (score 3):

I give two explanations:

1. Basically, low of vertex V1 is depth of another vertex to which you can get if DFS further from V1, and if you can't get back to any vertex which was discovered prior to V1, then removing V1 would split the graph.
2. Observe, that if after visiting all vertex children you haven't found a child with smaller low point than the vertex has that means that there is no cycling edges and removing this vertex would split the graph.

[image]

Comment: Is your second point is true for this type of graph [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_graph) .

Comment: I think the algorithm works in this way case 1- if root has more than two children then its an articulation point . (ie the childcount should be greater than 2)

Comment: case 2 - For remaining non root nodes , the lowpoint helps to determine a cycle                      (   i.e   biconnected component)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)

Comment: @RajGopalbh4 Well, you are right, lowpoints help to determine a cycle presence. I thought you wanted somebody to explain it.

Comment: yes this point needed to be included everywhere . Thank you Yola .

Comment: @RajGopalbh4 both cases (clauses) explain the same just in different words. If you think this answers your question you might want to accept the answer and maybe upvote it.